# Power BI Expression.Error: The name wasn't recognized. Make sure it's spelled correctly

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, data-manipulation, powerbi-desktop, m

First of all - thank you to those who have helped with coding so far... I'm hoping this is the last problem with my code to use the Autotask API.

Syntax is passing in Power BI and in Chat GPT and what I think it should be but gatherpagingdata seems to fail. From what I can see it can be a general error so I'm not sure I am even in the same place.

I'm hoping I can get this working and share with the Autotask community and this would unlock a lot of functionality.

Thanks in advance

Error

> Expression.Error: The name 'gatherpagingdata' wasn't recognized.  Make
> sure it's spelled correctly.

```
let
// NB Making calls to multiple instances from the same Power BI Dash can cause problems with authentication
// https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fstsQMZiHME
// check data source security

    // Common parameters
    //texttoconv = "dddd",
    //text = texttoconv as text,
    queryStringApiIntegrationCodevar = "xxxx",
    queryStringUserNamevar = "xxxxxx",
    queryStringUserSecretvar = "xxxxx",
    queryStringContentTypevar = "application/json",
    headers = [#"ApiIntegrationCode"=queryStringApiIntegrationCodevar, #"UserName"=queryStringUserNamevar, #"Secret"=queryStringUserSecretvar, #"Content-Type"=queryStringContentTypevar],
    apiUrl = "https://webservices4.autotask.net/ATServicesRest/V1.0/Projects/query",
    apiUrlnew = "https://webservices4.autotask.net/ATServicesRest/V1.0/Projects/query/next",
    searchFilter = "{""filter"":[{""op"":""gte"",""field"":""id"",""value"":""0""}]}",    


//Functions

converturl = (data as text) as text => 
let
    out = Uri.Parts("http://contoso?a=" & Text.Replace(data, "&", "%26"))[Query][a]
in
    out,

gatherpagingdata = (data as list, uri as text) =>
    let
        // Get the Data
       // Replace Percent URL-encoded characters
        nextpagefunc = converturl(uri),
        //nextpagefunctest = try newURIwhatisit(uri) otherwise error uri,
        textBeforePaging = Text.BeforeDelimiter(nextpagefunc, "?paging"),
        textAfterPaging = Text.BetweenDelimiters(nextpagefunc, "paging=", " "),

        newReq = try Json.Document(Web.Contents(textBeforePaging, [Headers=headers, Query=[paging=textAfterPaging]]))[pageDetails][nextPageUrl] otherwise error "Failed to retrieve data from the API Gather",
        newdata = newReq[items],

       // Add that data to rolling aggregate
        updatedData = List.Combine({data, newdata}),

        // Check for the next URL using function
        nextPageUrl = newReq[pageDetails][nextPageUrl],

       // If there's no next page of data, return. If there is, call @gather again to get more data
       result = if nextPageUrl <> null then gatherpagingdata(updatedData, nextPageUrl) else updatedData
   in
       result,


//Execute
    //initReq = Json.Document(Web.Contents(apiUrl, headers)),
    initReq = try Json.Document(Web.Contents(apiUrl, [Headers=headers, Query=[search=searchFilter]])) otherwise error "Failed to retrieve data from the API 1st Pass",
    //initReq = try Json.Document(Web.Contents(apiUrl, headers)) otherwise error apiUrl,
    initData = initReq[items],


    //before we call gather(), we want see if its even necesarry. First request returns only one page? Return.
    //outputList = try if initReq[pageDetails][nextPageUrl] = null then initData else gather(initData, BaseURI)otherwise error uri,
    uri = initReq[pageDetails][nextPageUrl],

    // Decode the extracted value 

       // Replace Percent URL-encoded characters
        nextpagefunc = converturl(uri),

    outputList = if initReq[pageDetails][nextPageUrl] = null then 
        initData 
    else 
        gatherpagingdata(initData, uri),
    //then place records into a table. This will expand all columns available in the record.
    expand = Table.FromRecords(outputList)
in
    expand
```

Comment: Try adding an @ sign in a recursive function. e.g.  result = if nextPageUrl <> null then @gatherpagingdata(updatedData, nextPageUrl) else updatedData

Comment: Hi - that seemed to remove the error for not reconginsing it as a function (got another to fix now lol) - what did the @ sign do in this context please ? Thanks T

Comment: It's how you call a recursive function in PQ. I can add as an answer so you can mark as solved and then add a new question with the new error.

Comment: If you can that would be great... I'm still having an issue running that function though... It gives me the option to invoke manually but does not run. I'm wondering if its not getting some thing passed through right as I can see the vars been created. If this was VBA I'd step in but as its not running it I cant see any function var contents... T

Comment: I think its the headers - Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type Record to type List - Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type Record to type List.. T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding an @ sign in a recursive function. e.g.

```
result = if nextPageUrl <> null then @gatherpagingdata(updatedData, nextPageUrl) else updatedData
```